# Activity get API3 does not return case activity

Tags: api, civicase, activity

Im using API3 to get activities

My code is

```
function hook_any_activity_get($cid,$type) {
  $params = [
    'contact_id' => $cid,
    'activity_type_id' => $type,
    'sequential' => 1,
    'is_deleted' => 0,
  ];
  try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('Activity', 'get', $params);
  }
  catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // Handle error here.
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    return [
      'is_error' => 1,
      'error_message' => $errorMessage,
      'error_code' => $errorCode,
      'error_data' => $errorData,
    ];
  }
  return $result;
}
```

This works fine when the activity is created outside of a case.

When the activity is created within a case I get an error

One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Positive

I have tried this written into a module and in Drupal rules. Same error.

I'm not seeing anything in backtrace or the CiviCRM log file.

Ive even tried it just by trying to return the activity using the activity ID.

I also tried it by including the case ID

Comment: Are you on the latest civicrm version?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is a bug in the CiviMobile extension that is breaking this functionality. Disabling this extension fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for a case activity API, although I have not tested it for a while! https://civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivity-api
That might help you?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter `contact_id` should be `target_contact_id` (if looking for client) or `source_contact_id` (if looking for author).

Comment: There is a catchall for any activity contact in the API called contact_id...but I tried your suggestion as well - same error.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a stack trace in ConfigAndLog? I don't get an error.

Comment: I wish. Nothing. Are you using PHP to test or are you using the API explorer?

Comment: I used `cv php:eval`. Actually if you're catching the exception yourself then there won't be a stacktrace in the log. You can either put debug_backtrace() in your error handler, or let civi log the error instead (don't catch the error).

Comment: OK on this I used a Drupal view to get the ID of the activity I wanted. I put this into a Drupal rule to load the activity entity by activity ID - and it will not load it there either. Im just wondering if when it is part of a case, there is a permissions issue with it?

Comment: I also just tried using the APIto do the same thing and it returns the error even if you use the activity ID.

Comment: Actually I just tried it as user 1 and there was no error so it must be permissions.